# javascript inheritance using the prototype property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to do inheritance in javascript. First of all, looking on the web I found this

```
function A() {}
function B(){}
B.prototype = new A() ;
B.prototype.constructor = B ;
```

This works, however when I use the prototype property of B it doesn't work anymore ( http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/eQBUx/ )

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'A'; }

function B() {}
B.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'B'; }
```

I realize you could do

```
function B(){ this.bar = function(){ ... } } ;
```

But I think this is definitely slower than defining it using the prototype. So how could I do inheritance in the second situation ?

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'A';}

function B() {}
B.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'B'; }
B.prototype = new A() ; // replaces B's "bar" with A's "bar

var b = new B ;
console.log(b.bar());
```

As you can see the problem is in your 6th line. You're first setting `B.prototype.bar` to a function in line 5 and then you immediately set `B.prototype` to `new A` in line 6 (effectively undoing what you did in line 5). The solution is to put line 6 before line 5:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'A';}

function B() {}
B.prototype = new A() ; // now it will work
B.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'B'; }

var b = new B ;
console.log(b.bar());
```

See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/eQBUx/1/

In addition I agree with Bergi: [Stop using the `new` keyword](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#stop_using_the_new_keyword).

---

**Update:** After reading your comment and understanding your problem in greater detail I would recommend you use my [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library for inheritance:

```
var A = Object.augment(function () {
    this.constructor = function () {};

    this.bar = function () {
        return "A";
    };
});

var B = A.augment(function (base) {
    this.constructor = function () {};

    this.bar = function () {
        return "B" + base.bar.call(this);
    };
});

var b = new B;

console.log(b.bar());
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eQBUx/2/

Comment: Thnx, but I (and I didn't mentioned it, sorry) want to be able to call the overridden function, it will look like this: B.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'B' + this.$super(); }. Where $super probably does something Object.getPrototypeOf(this)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Aadit's answer will work fine, I have posted another answer on inheritance and overriding here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 Look under `Overriding functions` That answer is more an into to prototype in JS with code to fiddle with.

Comment: @HMR Cool. Personally I like my [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library more. It provides inheritance, encapsulation, private state, base prototype access, singletons, the module pattern and a bunch of additional functional features all in just 17 lines of code. I even wrote a blog post on it: [Standardizing Harmony Classes](http://aaditmshah.github.io/standardizing-harmony-classes/)

Answer (score 2):

Using `this` to assign properties breaks the prototype chain. It's very inefficient and you can't use it to get inheritance. So .. don't?

Comment: It doesn't alter the prototype chain, so how would it break it?

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: I usually use `this` for instance specific property values and prototype for default values of immutable property values and functions. Using `prototype.someArray` can cause unexpected results when doing something like `instance1.someArray.push("on all instances")` But would work perfectly fine to define default values like `Person.prototype.hands=2` Here is some detail when I'd use `this` or `prototype` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a property on a the prototype object which you completely replace afterwards. Do it the other way round, create the `bar` method on the *new* object. And [don't use `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!

```
function B() {}
// first create the prototype object
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
// then assign properties on it
B.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'B'; }
```